# Spring core container is the basis for complete Spring framework?

Tags: spring

All websites state that the Spring core container is the basis for complete Spring framework i.e., it is used across
the all modules like AOP, JDBC module, Web module, etc. As per my understanding, the Spring core container's main purpose is
to inject dependencies, so avoiding the need of factory classes and methods. Is that correct?

Second question: When it is said, Spring core container is the basis for complete Spring framework (e.g., for Spring AOP). As per my understanding, in Spring AOP also, getting the object of classes like
`ProxyFactoryBean` is achieved by core container. Right?

Thirdly, it is stated that Spring core container avoids the need for programming the use of  singletons. How come singleton
classes are avoided by core container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. yep
2. yep
3. All beans declared in Spring config files are singleton by default. They are instantiated when your application starts.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Just wanted to confirm two things: can we have two core containers in a given application with following code? -- BeanFactory factory1 = new XmlBeanFactory("MyXml") , BeanFactory factory2 = new XmlBeanFactory("MyXml") . Second point is even if we If we declare the public constructor in bean we will have singleton instance, if we are getting it from core container. Right?

Comment: 1. Yes, you can have 2 core containers, but you shouldn't. In the contrary, you should take care to have only one container to be sure transactions will work correctly (You can split bean declarations in multiple xml files though). 2. Sure, as long as you get it from the container.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your understanding of what you get from Spring is about right. So let's get on to your third question, the interesting one.

The key is it's not that you don't have singletons, it's that they're singletons by configuration. This is a vital difference, as it means you can avoid all the complicated singleton enforcement code (the source of frequent problems) and instead just write exceptionally simple programs that focus on the business end of things. This is particularly important when you are writing a program with non-trivial object lifetimes: for example, in a webapp it makes it very easy to manage the lifespan of objects that hold state associated with a user's session, since if the objects have `session` scope, they'll be “singleton per user session”. That's enormously easier to work with than many of the alternatives.

The fact that Spring can also help out with transactions is just perfect as transaction handling is distinctly non-trivial, and AOP is the best solution to them in Java that I've seen (other languages have other options open) with Spring supporting a pretty straight-forward way of doing it. Try to do it properly without if you don't believe me. Spring's pretty much wonderful.